# website shows unavailable while taking DB backup?

Tags: mysql, linux, web-services, amazon-web-services, drupal-7

My website is created using Drupal 7 on one instance of amazon & database is on amazon RDS . whenever i am taking backup of database using Mysql with root user & simultaneously when a developer try to clear the cache on the website that time website goes offline untill backup gets over say for around 30 min this happens everytime . what is the solution to avoid this problem.

Comment: which storage engine is using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use  this parameter when taking backup with `mysqldump` . `--lock-tables` for MyISAM storage engine. `--single-transaction` for Innodb storage engine.

`--lock-tables` Lock all tables before dumping them. The tables are locked with READ LOCAL to allow concurrent inserts in the case of MyISAM tables.

For transactional tables such as InnoDB and BDB, `--single-transaction` is a much better option, because it does not need to lock the tables at all`.--single-transaction` produces a checkpoint that allows the dump to capture all data prior to the checkpoint while receiving incoming changes. Those incoming changes do not become part of the dump. That ensures the same point-in-time for all tables.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying . but i am taking backup using MYSQL administrator application which is installed on windows system .

Comment: @s.tait for your knowledge mysql administrator utility is discontinue. Mysql workbench has replaced this. In workbench, when you export data then there is option `advance settings / options` where you can lock tables. try this

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution  . I will try mysql workbench and will inform you .

Answer (score 0):

You could create a read replica and perform the mysqldump against the replica, to keep the load off the main server. https://aws.amazon.com/rds/details/read-replicas/